# can not read image from folder in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have put images inside "/public/images" path. Now in the respose I am getting url as I wanted. But as soon as I paste that url to web browser, it says **Cannot GET /public/images/food-1-xxhdpi.png**. So should I write separate API to handle that?

Main file app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var PORT = 3000;
var foodtrucklist = require('./controller/foodtrucklist.js');
var foodtruck = require('./model/datafoodtruck');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/quflip');

mongoose.connection.once('connected', function() {
    console.log("Connected to database")
    foodtruck.save(function(err,foodtrucks){
        if (err) res.send(err);
    });
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));


app.get('/foodtrucklist',foodtrucklist);

app.listen(PORT,function() {
    console.log('express listining on port' + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

Maps the static content in the `/public/images` folder to the root of your web application. So the request `/public/images/food-1-xxhdpi.png` will only work if the full path is `.../public/images/public/images/food-1-xxhdpi.png`

You should either make your request for `/food-1-xxhdpi.png` or change the line of code to something like:

```
 app.use('/my-virtual-directory',express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

so that requests can be picked up in what ever you choose to make `/my-virtual-directory`

So... Your file in this case becomes `/my-virtual-directory/food-1-xxhdpi.png`

Obviously, you can still do this to make it map externally to the same way you have it internally with:

```
 app.use('/public/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

Here is more info on the static middleware for express: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: app.use('/public/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
 worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try back-end look like this.

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Then front end use this extract location like

```
<img src="images/your image name" alt="" />
```

Comment: "use only this for call static files" Why only that? Your statement is an absolute, and as such does not take into account context of the request, or that different requirements may make this advice incorrect.

Comment: I told you that you can use only this structure for calling static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

and when you will call image into front end then you can add your folder and name and image name with extension. 

it is not hard . just only simple problem

Comment: My comment highlighter the "only" part and the imperative nature of your statement. Your comment is very restrictive. You can do other things like set up specific virtual directories, use other paths, etc. So, not only the structure you advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Backend:

```
  var path = require('path');
  var app = express();
  var express = require('express');

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Frontend:

```
 <img src="/images/food-1-xxhdpi.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on project and next snippet of code working fine for me:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

and when I try to reach this in .hbs it is easy as:

```
<img src='/images/image.jpg'  alt='...' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type following `code` in your `app.js` file

```
app.use('/static/category/', express.static(__dirname+'/public/assets/category_pic/'));
```

now i will access image by using following `code`

```
<img src="/static/category/myimage.jpg" width="50" height="50">
```

here my actual path is  `/public/assets/category_pic/` but i convert it `/static/category/` using above line of code

now i able to access image file using this url `http://localhost:3000/static/category/myimage.jpg`